# Wordpress - PHP Fatal error: Interface 'Requests_Hooker' not found?

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, hook

i am not able to access my wordpress frontend. After uploading the 'understrap' theme my backend and frontend throw an http 500 exception. 
In order to debug the issue, i've set '**WP_DEBUG**' to '**true**' and receive the following exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Requests_Hooker' not found in /var/www/html/wp-includes/Requests/Hooks.php on line 15
```

Next, i've overwrite the complete "**wp-includes**" folder with an initial "wp-includes" from a new wordpess and now am able to access my backend again. Unfortunately, my frontend is still empty and in wp-content/debug.log is still the same exception.

Plugins, Themes and Uploads are not affecting the issue - that is sure (the first thing i did is to remove the uploaded theme - **understrap**). 
Wp-uploads folder has been completely **initialized**. 
Does anyone had this issue before and might know how to fix it? Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old request, but in case others have this issue, I found a solution today. It looks like someone deleted or renamed "Hooker.php" in "webroot/wp-includes/Requests". If you are able, I would recommend restoring a previous version of that file using whatever kind of control panel you are using to administrate your site.